# Restart the pipeline from a particular stage in jenkins scripted pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have 4 different stages(build test deploy monitor) in my pipeline which is build using scripted pipeline. Pipeline runs  till stage 3 completion and then waits for user input. Based on user input, I need to restart from stage 2 if the user confirms with pressing proceed after stage 3. is there any way to achieve this in scripted pipeline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like the below to cater your requirement.

```
node {
    def mvnHome
    def flag = false
    stage('Stage 1') {
       echo "This stage executed always"
    }
    // Lets execute stage 2
    generateStage2AndCall3("First Execution").call()
    
    stage('Get User Input') {
        echo "Getting user Input"
        input(message: "Should we continue?")
        generateStage2AndCall3("Second Execution").call()
    }
    
    stage('Stage 4') {
        echo "Result"
    }
}

def generateStage2AndCall3(name) {
    return {
        stage("Stage 2 ${name}") {
            echo "Stage 2 ${name}"
            generateStage3(name).call()
        }
    }
}

def generateStage3(name) {
    return {
        stage("Stage 3 ${name}") {
            echo "Stage 3 ${name}"
        }
    }
}
```

The execution will look like the below.

[image]

Comment: Sorry it looks like I could not put my question properly. Updated my question. My pipeline runs 1 2 3 and wait for user input and if click proceed it has to restart the pipeline from stage 2 skipping stage 1.

Comment: @user2636464 what do you want to do if the user press Abort? Still, execute stage 4?

Comment: If user press abort after  stage 3, pipeline is aborted there itself. If user press proceed, it should restart the pipeline from stage 2  onwards.

Comment: So that means your stage 4 never executes?

Comment: If user press proceed it should execute 2,3 and 4 .I am not able to handle this correctly.